# Library to embed ActionScript into C++

Tags: library, c++

I've never worked with action script or knew of its existence before so please bear with me.

I have some **ActionScript3** code which does some incredibly complicated maths to generate some models. I understand ActionScript is interpreted so I'd like to run that code from a C++ application and get the models and pictures that ActionScript code produces. Is there a library that I can use to do such a thing?

I have looked online and the only thing I could find was something related to using flash.